# Relation between homogeneity and categoricity

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

Define a structure $\mathcal{A}$ as *homogeneous* if, for every two substructures $\mathcal{B}, \mathcal{C}$ of $\mathcal{A}$, if $f: B \to C$ is an isomorphism, then $f$ extends to an automorphism of $\mathcal{A}$. Define a structure $\mathcal{A}$ as *$\lambda$-categorical* if there is, up to isomorphism, exactly one model $\mathcal{A}'$ of cardinality $\lambda$ satisfying $\mathrm{Th}(\mathcal{A})$. A structure is *totally* categorical if it's categorical in every infinite cardinal.

**Question**: is there any relation between homogeneity and (total) categoricity? In particular, does homogeneity imply (total) categoricity? If not, what is an example of a homogeneous structure which is not (totally) categorical?

I've been searching a lot for the answer for these question but without much success. I'm trying to understand these two concepts, so any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $(\mathbb N,0,S)$. It is vacuously homogenous because it doesn't have any proper substructures.

On the other hand, it is not even $\aleph_0$-categorical -- the usual compactness argument will produce an elementarily equivalent countable model with a nonstandard element, which cannot be isomorphic to $\mathbb N$.

---

If vacuous homogeneity feels like cheating, consider $(\mathbb Z,S)$ instead. This is more meaningfully homogeneous, and we can still use compactness to produce an elementarily equivalent countable structure that contains two elements that are not any finite distance from each other.

Comment: Nice! Are uncountable dense linear orders without endpoints also homogeneous? I know that countable dense linear orders without endpoints are homogeneous, but I was wondering about the uncountable case.

Comment: @Nagase: No, that was my first guess too, but it doesn't work. It's not homogenous as far as I can see -- the canonical countable dense linear order without endpoints is $\mathbb Q$, but it is isomorphic to its substructure $\mathbb Q\cap(0,1)$, and there aren't any elements left over to extend the isomorphism to an automorphism with! (On the other hand that theory _is_ $\aleph_0$-categorical; perhaps that's what you remember?).

Comment: Hmm, I had in mind the fact that for any two *finite* substructures of $\mathbb{Q}$, an isomorphism between them can be extended to an automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}$. So that *doesn't* imply homogeneity? Incidentally, if that's correct, this would be an example of an $\aleph_0$-categorical structure that's not homogeneous, right?

Comment: @Nagase: Correct, assuming you're quoting the definition correctly (I don't remember seeing "homogenous" outside this question, so I cannot opine on whether it is right).

Comment: I checked some sources and it seems there are several definitions of homogeneity. Another one restricts the substructures in my original question to *finite* (or finitely generated) substructures, so that $\mathbb{Q}$ would count as homogeneous according to that definition. It seems that both your examples would still hold under this new definition, right?

Comment: @Nagase: Yes, I think so.

Comment: In my experience, "homogeneous" *always* means that isomorphisms between finite or finitely generated substructures extend to automorphisms. There's another closely related notion in model theory of $\kappa$-strongly homogeneous, which says that if two tuples $\overline{a}$ and $\overline{b}$ of length $<\kappa$ have the same first-order type in $M$, then there is an automorphism of $M$ moving $\overline{a}$ to $\overline{b}$. Homogeneity in the sense of your original question (without a bound on the size: finite or $<\kappa$) will be extremely rare.

Comment: Another example you might be interested in: Uncountable DLOs are not necessarily even (finitely) homogeneous. For example, consider $M = \mathbb{R}\cup \mathbb{Q}$, where all the elements in $\mathbb{Q}$ are greater than all the elements in $\mathbb{R}$. Then if $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $b\in \mathbb{Q}$, $\{a\}$ is isomorphic to $\{b\}$, but there is no automorphism of $M$ moving $a$ to $b$, since there are uncountably many $c>a$ but only countably many $c>b$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman - (For some reason I just noticed your comments now) Thanks, that's helpful. In any case, the examples from Henning still hold, because the only finitely generated substructures of $(\mathbb{Z}, S)$ will be sets such as $\{ x : x > a\}$ for some $a$, and any isomorphism between such sets will extend to an isomorphism of the whole structure, right? Is there any restriction on homogeneous structures to relational structures?

Comment: Yes, that's right.